# Is there a way the CAPS LOCK key can perform its normal text function of toggling uppercase letters off and on for fiction writing in EMACS?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes, keyboard-layout, capitalization

I'm a new Emacs user and New to LINUX. I only use EMACS for screenwriting using fountain mode. As such, the CAPS LOCK key is a hugely-used key in screenwriting. From some googling, I see EMACS uses caps lock for other things. For my use case, is there any way to get emacs to treat the caps lock key as a regular caps lock for writing purposes so that it toggles uppercase letters on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken. Try starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). Emacs doesn't use the Caps Lock key for anything. By default it doesn't even see an event from pressing it.

Some users like to make the Caps Lock key function as a Ctrl key, but Emacs doesn't do that by default. Maybe you're picking up some package or other code that's doing that behind your back.

If so, bisect your init file, to file the culprit, if your Caps Lock key is being hijacked to do something else for Emacs.

FWIW, I use the Caps Lock key normally, just as you say you want to do. When I'm editing stretches of code that need to be uppercase I just toggle it on. Then I toggle it off again for the (longer) stretches of code that are mixed case.

Comment: Thank you for this.